# Where are other drives?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I just installed Ubuntu on virtual box in Windows 10. But it doesn't show even a single file already there in my drive C, D and E. The file appear on Windows explorer but not in Ubuntu File manager. How to access these files?

Comment: means you have to access windows file on ubuntu ?

Comment: Use the shared folders feature in Virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

Inside virtual box, the guest os (in your case, Ubuntu) will see only the virtual drive you created to install Ubuntu. If you want to access files on other drives, you can use shared folders to do so.

For information on how to use shared folders, look [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868) for Linux guest, and look [here](http://virtuatopia.com/index.php/VirtualBox_Shared_Folders) for Windows guest.